# Venus flytrap pollination

Tags: flowering, pollination, carnivorous-plants, venus-fly-trap

I've just found out that my Venus flytraps (dionaea muscipula) is going growing several flowers this year.

[image: Stems]

I was wondering if it's worth trying to cross-pollinate them.
In that case: how? when?

It also seems that one of the plants is giving not one, but two flower stems (the smaller one is still too tiny and almost not visible in the pic). Should I cut the smaller one? Or should I let it grow freely?

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q-tip.  Make the rounds of the blooms twice, touching both stamens and pistils. First round picks up pollen, 2nd round distributes pollen.

You will get a few small black seeds from each flower.  If they don't bloom at the same time,  you can try keeping the q-tip in the freezer to keep pollen from one flower for the next one to bloom.

Comment: Nice, thanks. About the plant that is giving two flower steams, should I cut the smaller one?

Comment: @motagirl2 that’s actually a second question... but: no, just let it be.